# Let user add field to Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am building a form that allows employees to enter the city, state of trip legs and calculate their mileage reimbursement automatically.  Right now I have the following code in forms.py:

```
leg1a = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg1b = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg2a = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg2b = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg3a = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg3b = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg4a = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg4b = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg5a = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg5b = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg6a = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
leg6b = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
```

I then use a separate script to tally the miles in each leg and multiply the total by our mileage rate.  It works, but it is ugly on the form; The form has six pairs of fields that are all optional.  I would like to have 1 pair to start, and an option the user can click to add another leg.

I need to keep the data in tuple form, like so: `('city, ST','city2, ST')` for the distance calculation function.

Here is the code I currently use in my form views for cleaning and sending the data to the mileage handler:

## Mileage distance calculation

```
        leg_list = [(leg1a, leg1b), (leg2a, leg2b), (leg3a, leg3b), (leg4a, leg4b), (leg5a, leg5b), (leg6a, leg6b)]
        
        cleaned_leg_list = []
        #get rid of empty variables
        for leg in leg_list:
            if leg == ('',''):
                pass
            else:
                cleaned_leg_list.append(leg)
        leg_distance = []
        #sends each leg of mileage claim to distance handler
        for leg in cleaned_leg_list:
            pre_leg = main(leg)
            leg_distance.append(pre_leg)
        #sums legs of mileage claim 
        sum_distance = sum(leg_distance)
```

Comment: Normalize harder. And formsets.

Answer (score 3):

Use one form and a formset. A formset handles dealing with multiple instances of one form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Optionally, you can look into cloning formsets via javascript to dynamically add as many areas as you want without reloading the view.

This is also a great opportunity to clean up your code - put a method on the form definition that calculates leg distance and calls your external script. Your views can do the summation in a few lines of code!

You can even build the formset class yourself and add the summation function there, so your view is as simple as: `if formset.is_valid(): print formset.sum_leg_distances()`

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    start_city = forms.CharField()
    start_state = forms.CharField()
    end_city = forms.CharField()
    end_state = forms.CharField()

MyFormSet = formset_factory(form=MyForm, extra=6)

def my_view(request):
   formset = MyFormSet(request.POST or None)
   if request.POST:
       if formset.is_valid():
           for form in formset.forms:
               form.cleaned_data['start_city'] # here's your leg data.
               # form.calculate_leg_distance()
           # sum([form.calculat_leg_distance() for form in formset])


   return render(request, 'my_template', {'formset': formset})

<form method="post">
   {{ formset.as_p }}
   {{ formset.management_form }}
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```